# Changing variable deletes other variable in Jenkins groovy-script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I use a **free style job** in Jenkins that has 2 Parameters that the user can change at the start:

- ReleaseBuild - boolean
- PluginVersion - string

I use a **system groovy script** to read an change the variables

First I read the content of `ReleaseBuild`:

```java
def isRelease = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ReleaseBuild").toString();
println "Is ReleaseBuild: " + isRelease
```

The output shows the correct value: `Is ReleaseBuild: true`

I need to replace the content of the second variable:

```java
def verParameter = new StringParameterValue('PluginVersion', '1.0')
build.addOrReplaceAction(new ParametersAction(verParameter))
```

Now I check the content of `ReleaseBuild` variable again:

```java
def isStillRelease = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ReleaseBuild").toString();
println "Is ReleaseBuild: " + isStillRelease
```

Now the variable seems to be gone. Output: `Is ReleaseBuild: null`

How can I change the content of `PluginVersion` without deleting `ReleaseBuild` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem meanwhile with a **workaround**:
When I want to update the value, I update all values (this is ok here, since I only have two)

```java
def verParameter = new StringParameterValue('PluginVersion', ver)
def relParameter = new BooleanParameterValue('ReleaseBuild', isRelease)
build.addOrReplaceAction(new ParametersAction(verParameter, relParameter))
```

Still hoping to get a better solution but at least it works.